# How to reinforce type of object from an interface

Tags: typescript

i have the following interface:

```
export interface CommandRequest {
  action: string;
  parameter: {
    source: string;
  }
}
```

I use it to build an object like this:

```
const commandRequest: CommandRequest = req.body;
```

Where req.body is the body of an http call.

Now, i want to store the commandRequest in a dictionary, that i keep like this:

```
const notepad = {
  commands: {}
};

export default notepad;
```

But i get the following error:
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.

How should i change the code to specify the type of the dictionary?

Comment: Should `commands` key be an array of `CommandRequest`?

Comment: Yes @AndréKrosby, i mean, it should be a dictionary where keys are strings and values are CommandRequests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the comment above, you can do this:

```js
interface Notepad {
  commands: Record<string, CommandRequest>
}

const notepad = {
  commands: {}
}

export default notepad
```

`Record` docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Comment: Can this be update for a dictionary? Where the key is a string, and the value is a CommandRequest?

Comment: Check my updated answer.